# Which tags need to be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, tags

Which tags need to be cleaned up by a user with elevated editing or tag privileges?

*Instead of posting a new answer per tag, feel free to just edit the CW answer.*

Comment: Should synonymization be addressed here, too?

Comment: @HDE for sure, I added sections in the CW post but commented out the headings since I didn't have any to add

Comment: There are a few other questions about specific tags: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/145/merge-hdd-into-hard-disk and http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/138/merge-micro-pc-into-mini-pc

Comment: I asked another related question: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/147/are-full-tag-names-or-abbreviations-preferred

Comment: @kasperd I deleted my tag request you linked to because it was being overlooked completely.

Answer (score 5):

### Renames

- [headtracking](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headtracking) → [head-tracking](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/head-tracking) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [powerbank](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerbank) → [power-bank](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-bank) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [lifespan](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifespan) → [life-span](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-span)
- [graphic-cards](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-cards) → [graphics-cards](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-cards) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [webserver](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver) → [web-server](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-server) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [thinclient](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thinclient) → [thin-client](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thin-client) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [ebook](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook) → [e-reader](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-reader) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [onboard-raid](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onboard-raid) → [raid](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raid) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Deletes

- [comfort](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comfort) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [with](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/with) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [gadgets](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [microwave](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microwave) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [shredder](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shredder) - [closed as out-of-scope](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/232/small-business-shredder-with-autofeeding-capabilities)
- [playstation-4](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-4) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Synonyms

- [hdd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) → [hard-disk](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ([reference](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/57))
- [notebook](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notebook) → [laptop](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ([reference](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207/60))
- [ultrabook](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultrabook) → [laptop](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Merges

- [hdd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) → [hard-disk](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ([reference](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/57))

Comment: Because no one else has commented on it yet, I am fine with renaming [lifespan] to [life-span].

Comment: @Cfinley Seconded. As much as I use _lifespan_ and not _life span_, both [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/life-span?q=lifespan) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life%20span) use _life span_.