# Merge [hdd] into [hard-disk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed my first question which I had tagged [hard-disk](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk) got retagged as [hdd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd). I prefer the full name rather than the abbreviation. But most of all, I think one of those two tags should definitely be a synonym for the other.

Which of the two does the community think should be merged into the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. A tag synonym mapping [hdd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) → [hard-disk](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk) was created.

Answer (score 3):

From the [tags](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page of the site, it can be seen that the convention which is being generally followed is the full-name with a `-` in the middle.

In fact, it is more clear and self-explanatory too, rather than abbreviations.

So, `hard-disk` should be the correct tag and every tag related to it like `hdd` can be merged into it.

Comment: As far as I can tell 1250 reputation is required to make them synonyms and the highest reputation any user has so far is 900. So we'll have to wait until somebody has enough reputation or a moderator steps in to do it.