# Merge [notebook] into [laptop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I propose merging [notebook](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notebook) into [laptop](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop) and making an appropriate synonym.

There are currently 3 [notebook](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notebook) questions and 5 [laptop](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop) questions. All are referring to the same type of hardware.

Comment: Wait what? Notebooks are laptops? I'm *really* confused...

Comment: @Zizouz212 the moleskin laptop is the best!

Comment: @Zizouz212 [Notebook computers](https://www.google.com/search?q=notebook&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIneuE_IqayAIVxBOSCh2EcwTL&biw=1600&bih=1078#tbm=isch&q=notebook+computer)

Comment: No, [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24377854#24377854) is a notebook.

Comment: I've been really enjoying programming with my new Papermate Notebook. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

A synonym mapping [notebook](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notebook) → **[laptop](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop)** (main tag) was created.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please. ["Notebook computer" even redirects to laptop on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notebook_computer). As far as I can tell, 'notebook' started out as a marketing thing and then got picked up by the press, then consumers, as a synonym for 'laptop'.

Comment: "Notebook" is basically another one of those awful industry buzzwords.

Comment: @Adam Which sadly is incredibly misleading.